# On shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, how to choose UIView rotation direction?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I rotate the iPhone, I want the UIView to rotate the opposite direction that it is doing.
How do I choose the direction to rotate?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, place an IF statement.

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) (angle / 180.0 * M_PI)

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {

    //Rotate view here by 180 degrees
    CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    rotation = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(180));

    view.transform = rotation;

}
```

Please note that  rotating to the direction opposite of what the user expects will result in your app being rejected.

Comment: BTW, you usually shouldn't make changes like that in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, rather in `willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.  'Should' ought to be quick and efficient in simply determining if a rotation is permitted to occur.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant to put. Thanks for pointing that out!